# How to design to avoid two-way reference between two tables

Tags: database-design, foreign-key

I am having a problem with foreign keys between two tables. I am trying to model a relationship between members of a club and their relatives. This is a straightforward many-to-one relationship, with many relatives related to one member. However, one and just one of this relatives must be the main contact. Also, many members can have the same relative as main contact (siblings to their father as an example).

EDIT: Members are kids, and relatives must be adults, so **relatives can't be members**, and **members can't be main contact of another member**.

A FK on member table refering the PK of relatives would work, but this will leave me with a circular reference and a "chicken-or-egg" problem.

What is the right approach to this kind of problems? Maybe I am just thinking it too much.

Schema is more or less like this:

```
+--------------+    +-------------+
| member       |    | relatives   |
+--------------+    +-------------+
|id            |<-+ |id           |<-+
|name          |  +-|*member_id   |  |
|address       |    |name         |  |
|phone         |    |relationship |  |
|...           |    |phone        |  |
|*main_contact |-+  |...          |  |
+--------------+ |  +-------------+  |
                 +-------------------+
```

Comment: Besides hte question you ask, it looks like the relationship (`relatives(member_id) REFERENCES member(id)`) should be many-to-many, not one-to-many.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you may need a self-join:

1. Get rid of the relatives table entirely
2. Define the `main_contact` as a foreign_key to the `id` column of the `member` table.

Or depending on the relationship a many-to-many resolver table in the middle:

1. Get rid of `member_id` from `relatives`
2. Get rid of `main_contact`
   from from `member`
3. Add a new table `member_relative` with the
   columns `member_id`, `relative_id` and a column to indicate
   `relationship_type`.

Comment: If you get rid of the `relatives` table, you have eliminated the 1-to-many relationship between a member and a relative.

Comment: I can't use a single table, as relatives can't be members.

Comment: Thinking a bit more about it, it seems that @ypercube and Mack are right, this should be a many to many relationship, as a member has many relatives, and a relative can be main contact to many members.